# How to enhance my subquery with two tables to search with 3 tables if the main table have 2 primary keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, subquery

The main table is 'M_Order' which contains orders and its details

```
M_order
row_id |Order_Num | Order_Status | created     | created_by | Account_ID
--------------------------------------------------------------
1-a    | 1        | complete     | 2016-08-25  |    jhon    | 3-a
1-b    | 2        | pending      | 2016-08-26  |    mike    | 3-b
1-c    | 3        | failed       | 2015-08-27  |    mike    | 3-c
1-d    | 4        | pending      | 2015-08-25  |    jhon    | 3-d
1-e    | 5        | failed       | 2016-08-26  |    mike    | 3-e
1-f    | 6        | New          | 2017-03-27  |    jhon    | 3-f
```

The 2nd table is 'Order_itmes' which contain lists of products for each order

```
Order_itmes
row_id |Order_id | Product_ID
--------------------------------------------------------------
2-a    | 1-a     |  Prod_1    
2-b    | 1-b     |  Prod_2   
2-c    | 1-c     |  Prod_1 
2-d    | 1-d     |  Prod_1    
2-e    | 1-e     |  Prod_1   
2-f    | 1-f     |  Prod_3
```

The row_id from 'M_order' table is unique and available in the table 'Order_items' as Order_id

I have a query which show the orders with specific product_id from 'Order_items'

```
Select Order_Num,Order_status,created ,created_by
  from M_order where row_id in (select Order_id from Order_itmes where 
Product_ID='Prod_1')
  where Order_Status='Failed'
     Order By created desc
```

If I have a 3rd table 'Accounts' which having column row_id as the same column in account_id from 'M_Order'

```
 Accounts
 row_id  | Name 
--------------------------------------------------------------
 3-a     | cutomer1
 3-b     | cutomer2
 3-c     | cutomer3
 3-d     | cutomer4
 3-e     | cutomer5
 3-f     | cutomer6
```

how can I enhance the above query to list the customer name in results and shows as the following

```
Order_Num | Order_status | created   | created_by  |  name
-------------------------------------------------------------   
5         | failed       |2016-08-26 | mike        | customer5
3         | failed       |2015-08-27 | mike        | customer3
```

Comment: sql-server **or** mysql  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's better to use `JOIN` in this case as sub queries will get complicated once we have more than 2 tables. A simple `JOIN` would work here, e.g.:

```
SELECT o.order_num, o.order_status, o.created, o.created_by, a.name
FROM m_order o JOIN order_items oi ON o.row_id = oi.order_id
JOIN accounts a ON o.account_id = a.row_id
WHERE oi.product_id = 'Prod_1';
```

Comment: Thanks , this one worked like charm , even I tweaked little to include more than 4 tables .

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `join` to `Accounts`

```
select o.Order_Num, o.Order_status, o.created, o.created_by, a.name
from M_order o
  inner join Accounts a
    on o.Account_ID = a.row_id
where o.row_id in (
    select Order_id 
    from Order_items 
    where Product_ID='Prod_1'
    )
  and o.Order_Status='Failed'
order by o.created desc
```

Answer (score 0):

How can table have 2 PK ?

I am not commenting on index because you hv posted the real table structure and real data type.

What is the purpose of IDs as 1-a or 2-a or 3-a ?

Table should auto-increment id as CI.

Also Order table contain million of record so you can't simply query any thing without using paging.

Try this,

```
declare @M_order table(row_id varchar(30),Order_Num int,Order_Status varchar(30)
,created date,created_by varchar(30),Account_ID varchar(30))

insert into @M_order 
values 
('1-a',1,'complete','2016-08-25','jhon','3-a')
,('1-b',2,'pending','2016-08-26','mike','3-b')
,('1-c',3,'failed','2015-08-27','mike','3-c')
,('1-d',4,'pending','2015-08-25','jhon','3-d')
,('1-e',5,'failed','2016-08-26','mike','3-e')
,('1-f',6,'New ','2017-03-27','jhon','3-f')

declare @Order_itmes table(row_id varchar(30),Order_id varchar(30), Product_ID varchar(30))

insert into @Order_itmes 
values 
('2-a','1-a','Prod_1'),('2-b','1-b','Prod_2'),('2-c','1-c','Prod_1') 
,('2-d','1-d','Prod_1'),('2-e','1-e','Prod_1'),('2-f','1-f','Prod_3') 

declare @Accounts table(row_id varchar(30),Name varchar(30)) 

insert into @Accounts 
values
 ('3-a','cutomer1') ,('3-b','cutomer2') ,('3-c','cutomer3')
 ,('3-d','cutomer4') ,('3-e','cutomer5') ,('3-f','cutomer6')


 select 
     mo.Order_Num ,mo.Order_status, mo.created, mo.created_by, name
 from 
     @M_order MO
 inner join 
     @Accounts A on mo.Account_ID = a.row_id
 where 
     Order_status = 'failed'
     and exists (select Order_id from @Order_itmes OI 
                 where Product_ID = 'Prod_1' and oi.Order_id = mo.row_id)
```

Comment: not 2 primary key but one for order table and the other is unique and primary for account table as for the index its not the real which we have its just an just the nearest explanation